# How should I politely say "I hope I can receive recognition"?

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

That is used to apply to a university program and I want to politely say that I hope I can enter your program.

Should that be

> I hope I could receive your recognition.

or

> I hope I would/might/may receive recognition.

or

> I wish I could receive recognition.

Is there any other way to say it?

Comment: You need to give us more information. Are you sending an email? And can you tell us what this "approval" is referring to? Is this "approval" referring to a holiday, a project you proposed, a scholarship you applied for, a permit you are seeking?

Comment: That's a good tip. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would "receive recognition" for something significant that you did, or something you did better than others. A **recognition** is close to an **award**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/recognition) says

> **2.1** Appreciation or acclaim for an achievement, service, or ability.
>
> *his work was slow to gain recognition*
>   *she received the award in recognition of her human rights work*

So I think it is a poor choice of word, implying that you think you might be better than the other applicants for the program, or deserve to be noticed. I would rephrase the sentence something like this

> I very much hope to get a place on your course/program.

although obviously there will be more than just that in the email.